# Unable to install snap package

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, snap

```
$ sudo snap install vlc
error: cannot install "vlc": Get https://search.apps.ubuntu.com/api/v1/snaps/details/vlc?confinement=strict: 
dial tcp: lookup search.apps.ubuntu.com on [::1]:53:
read udp [::1]:44642->[::1]:53:
read: connection refused
```

Help please! I have a good working Internet connection. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem i solved it by restarting the snapd service

```
sudo systemctl restart snapd.service
```